# Overriding jQuery error handling

Tags: jquery, ajax, solr

I have a web application which communicates with a Solr server through AJAX requests, (so all the queries are sent as JSONP requests). I read that jQuery [does not allow error handling through cross domain JSONP requests](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings), However Solr as a server does reply (see below) with specific information when an unsuccessful request is sent. Such as requesting to an unauthorized handler (403), a bad request (400) or a place in the domain not found (404), and these can be seen in the javascript console (both chrome and ff).

I want to implement some error handling for this messages so they appear on the webpage, but I cant seem to retrieve those messages. I am assuming the errors being printed on the console come from jQuery, as that is where the console is pointing me, but I dont want to change anything on the library without knowing exactly what I am doing. I have tried to use some of the functions of jQuery.AJAX such as fail() and error settings but they have no effect since it is a cross domain request.

From Javascript console:

```
GET http://localhost:8983/core0/select?facet=true... 400 (Bad Request) jquery-1.11.2.js:9829
GET http://localhost:8983/doesnt-exist/clustering?... 404 (Not Found)  jquery-1.11.2.js:9829
```

Comment: Those messages are from the browser, the part on the right tells you where the request originated from. I doubt you can detect status codes from jsonp requests.

Comment: So there is no way to display those messages onto the html webpage? Rather than the console.